# How to select a limited number of groups

Tags: sql, db2

I'm developing a report on BIRT for ControlDesk/Maximo and I need to show the most requested groups of tickets.

I got how to select a limited number of tickets by group in DB2 query, but it's not what I need. That being only the top 10 groups with most count(ticket class)

Thanks in regards

My SQL, so far, that doesn't show what I want is something like:

```
    select tktemplate.description as tk_description, sr.description as sr_description, sr.reportdate, sr.templateid from sr inner join tktemplate on sr.templateid = tktemplate.templateid GROUP BY sr.templateid, sr.reportdate, tktemplate.description, sr.description ORDER BY sr.templateid fetch first 10 rows only
```

But It only shows the overall 10 first rows, not first of each group

Comment: Does'nt Maximo/ControlDesk reporting do this automatically for you as a canned report ?

Comment: Post your query

Comment: Rams, there is no query, as I don't have any Idea on how to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY countvalue DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

I.e. sort by the count in descending order. Fetch only 10 rows.

`FETCH FIRST` is ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternative approach. Either give the same result

```
ORDER BY tickets_count DESC LIMIT 10
```

or

```
ORDER BY tickets_count DESC FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: it shows only first 10 rows of all query, I need first 10 of each group